# Pandas dataframe selective data cleaning post groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i am new to pandas and i would like to know how to clean data by extracting only parts of rows. Say i have a dataframe as follows:

```
column1      date    key
A            2016    SB
A            2017    B
B            2015    SB
C            2014    SB
C            2014    PB
C            2015    B
C            2016    SB
```

how do i clean the data such that for each of the same column1 value, i only extract the first two rows value and ignore the rest (for example on C value, only 2014 SB and 2014 PB is what i get) ?

```
column1      date    key
A            2016    SB
A            2017    B
B            2015    SB
C            2014    SB
C            2014    PB
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html), check also [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#taking-the-first-rows-of-each-group):

```
df = df.groupby('column1').head(2)
print (df)
  column1  date key
0       A  2016  SB
1       A  2017   B
2       B  2015  SB
3       C  2014  SB
4       C  2014  PB
```

Comment: it's difficult to top this one... ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
In [82]: df.loc[df.groupby('column1').cumcount().lt(2)]
Out[82]:
  column1  date key
0       A  2016  SB
1       A  2017   B
2       B  2015  SB
3       C  2014  SB
4       C  2014  PB
```

Answer (score 4):

Out of frustration with how true @MaxU's statement is... I came up with this ridiculous solution.

> ```
> df.groupby('column1').head(2)
> ```
>
> it's difficult to top this one... ;) – MaxU

```
df.drop_duplicates('column1').append(
    df[df.duplicated('column1')].drop_duplicates('column1')
)

  column1  date key
0       A  2016  SB
2       B  2015  SB
3       C  2014  SB
1       A  2017   B
4       C  2014  PB
```

Comment: interesting solution ! :)